# Implementation of cubical type theory as described in this paper?

Tags: implementation, cubical-type-theory

[Syntax and Models of Cartesian Cubical Type Theory](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Erwh/papers/uniform/uniform.pdf)

I'd like to understand this paper enough to know how to implement cubical type theory. However I'm confused about how cofibrations should be implemented. They are a central piece in the paper.

I started an [nbe implementation](https://gist.github.com/cheery/476f8b9fec8985ba78e23ed756b43872) that may help on the way. It handles intervals with de bruijn indices to allow case splitting under them, hopefully I got that correct.

Specifically I wonder what kind of computational behavior cofibrations refer to?

Comment: Let me shamelessly self-promote this https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.08232 and you need a union-find data structure to speed up the decision procedure of whether cofibs are true or not

Comment: You can check the actual implementation in https://github.com/RedPRL/kado. If you don’t have diagonals (CHM/CCHM as in the article above, i.e. Cubical Agda/cubicaltt), the problem is about DNF computations, that is, some search tree algorithms; diagonals (as in redtt/cooltt) make things more complicated, but it’s still very similar.

Comment: Do you also have the project that uses kado? I did just take a look at kado and didn't understand how it maps over to the things described in the paper.

Comment: There is https://github.com/RedPRL/cooltt/tree/main/src/core (obviously).